How to Derive the Characteristic Polynomial of a Companion Matrix?
I am working on a problem involving the characteristic polynomial of a companion matrix and need some help understanding the derivation. Here is the matrix in question:
$ C(p) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -c_0 \\
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -c_1 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & -c_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -c_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix} $
The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is claimed to be $( (-1)^n p(\lambda) )$ where $( p(\lambda) = \lambda^n + c_{n-1} \lambda^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1 \lambda + c_0 )$. I need to verify this and understand the derivation.
To show that the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $( C(p) )$ is $( (-1)^n p(\lambda) )$, we consider the general form of the given matrix and use the concept of the characteristic polynomial. The matrix $( C(p) )$ looks like this:
$ C(p) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -c_0 \\
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -c_1 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & -c_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -c_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix} $
The characteristic polynomial $( \chi_{C(p)}(\lambda) )$ of a matrix $( A )$ is generally calculated by $( \det(\lambda I - A) )$, where $( I )$ is the identity matrix. So we calculate:
$ \chi_{C(p)}(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - C(p)) = \det\left(\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & \cdots & 0 & c_0 \\
-1 & \lambda & \cdots & 0 & c_1 \\
0 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & c_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda & c_{n-1} + \lambda
\end{pmatrix}\right) $
Now we expand the determinant along the first row:
$ \chi_{C(p)}(\lambda) = \lambda \cdot \det\left(\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & \cdots & 0 & c_1 \\
-1 & \cdots & 0 & c_2 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & \lambda & c_{n-1} + \lambda
\end{pmatrix}\right) + (-1)^{n+1} c_0 \cdot \det\left(\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & \lambda & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & -1
\end{pmatrix}\right) $
Expanding the first matrix with $( \lambda )$ as a factor reveals that the recursive process of determinant calculation leads to the polynomial form $( \lambda^n + c_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + \dots + c_1\lambda + c_0 )$. The term $( (-1)^{n+1} c_0 )$ results in $( (-1)^n )$ for the determinant of the second matrix, as it is a lower triangular matrix with the diagonal $( -1 )$.
Thus, the characteristic polynomial is:
$ \chi_{C(p)}(\lambda) = \lambda^n + c_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + \dots + c_1\lambda + c_0 = p(\lambda) $
Assuming that $( p(\lambda) = \lambda^n + c_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + \dots + c_1\lambda + c_0 )$, this means that the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $( C(p) )$ is indeed $( (-1)^n p(\lambda) )$ if $( p(\lambda) )$ represents the given polynomial.
The sign $( (-1)^n )$ reflects the orientation or sign reversal in the determinant calculation, specifically for the construction of the matrix $( C(p) )$. The exact form $( (-1)^n p(\lambda) )$ depends on the specific definition of $( p )$, particularly on the signs and coefficients $( c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{n-1} )$.

At which step are you stuck? Also characteristic polynomial is $p(\lambda)$. No need of factor $(-1)^n$.

There is a much easier way of doing this; for any linear map $T$ the matrix representation of the linear map has the property $Te_i=T_{1,i}e_1+\ldots+T_{n,i}e_n$ and so, $Te_k=e_{k+1}$ for $k<n$ and $Te_n=-c_0e_1-c_1e_2-\ldots-c_{n-1}e_n$.

so is my proof correct?

Does not look right,  to start with you have a $\lambda$ instead of $-1$ in the formula for ${\mathrm{det}}(\lambda I - C)$. Also remember this is not a forum for people to check your calculations.
